# What are some well-known unbiased estimator of regression coefficient besides OLS estimator?

Tags: regression, least-squares, unbiased-estimator, computational-statistics, time-complexity

Is there any other unbiased estimator of regression coefficient than OLS? For instance, one might consider using unbiased estimator with less computational cost  (since OLS involves matrix inversion)?

Comment: This is an interesting question! I take it we can assume that the sample size ($n$) is larger than the number of features ($p$)?

Also, just to stress: matrix inversion is not required to find the OLS estimates. Only solving a linear system is required

Comment: Special case 1: If the design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is orthogonal, then OLS can be calculated in $2np$ flops, which will is hard to beat. Special case 2: if $X$ is the identity, the response vector itself is an unbiased estimator, which can be computed in $0$ flops. Perhaps there's more gains for less structured design matrices, though

Comment: The title does not seem to quite match the question; consider updating.